# if-then-else condition in validation xml

Tags: java, xml, struts

What I am looking for is that,

a. if nothing is entered in field A, then do not validate field B and field C
b. if something is entered in field A, then check for (depends="required") for field B and field C....

can this be done in validation.xml ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide the additional infor with xml content

Comment: Yes, it is; the best way to do it depends on the actual version of Struts you're using. Although personally I'd either create a custom validator, or do the additional complex validation in Java rather than XML: easier to test.